# from int to char array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
char ToByte(bool b[8])
{
    char c = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (b[j]) {
            c |= 1 << i;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

This function converts from bool to char

```
   int main() {
        int number = 979899101;

        bitset<32> byte4= number;
        cout << byte4 << endl;;
        bitset<8> byte;
        char op[4];
        for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
                byte[j] = byte4[i * 8 + j];
            cout << byte;

            bool var[8];
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
                var[j] = byte[j];

            op[i]=ToByte(var);
        }   
        cout << op; 
    }
```

I'm trying to get convertion from integer to char array but I'm getting bad result.          like ╗I↨]╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠Ţ        I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Read this first

Comment: What did you expect as output?

Comment: Are you sure that the result? Or you get only these garbage characters at the end of the output?

Comment: output should be: abce

Comment: your char array doesnt have a terminator character

Answer (score 0):

Your function that converts bool array to char works correctly.

Try this:

```
bool a[] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}; //97
bool b[] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}; //98
bool c[] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}; //99
bool d[] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}; //100
cout << ToByte(a) << ToByte(b) << ToByte(c) << ToByte(d) << endl;
```

So you need to decide, how to split big number (979899101) into pieces (`bitset<8> byte`), because your code in `main()` do is not what you expect.

It splits the long number `00111010011010000001001011011101` into 58(`00111010`), 104(`01101000`), 18(`00010010`) and 221(`11011101`)

off topic: sorry for my broken English, this isn't my native language.